# Prolog recursive square brackets

Tags: recursion, prolog

Given the code below, I am trying to call the last rule: `trans([[p],[q],[r]]).`

This should then recursively call `trans([P]), write, trans([P],[Q]]).`

However it appears to be calling `trans([P]), write, trans([P,Q]).`

Is there a way to override the reserved square bracket? Is there a better way to enable the recursion?

```
trans([P]) :- atom(P), write(P).
trans([~P]) :- write('Not '), trans([P]).

trans([P,Q]) :- trans(P), write(' or '), trans(Q).
trans([P,Q,R]) :- trans([P]), write(' or '), trans([Q,R]).
trans([P,Q,R,S]) :- trans([P]), write(' or '), trans([Q,R,S]).


trans([[P],[Q]]) :- trans([P]), write(' and '), trans([Q]).
trans([[P,Q],[R]]) :- trans([P,Q]), write(' and '), trans([R]).
trans([[P],[Q,R]]) :- trans([P]), write(' and '), trans([Q,R]).
trans([[P,Q],[R,S]]) :- trans([P,Q]), write(' and '), trans([R,S]).

trans([[P],[Q],[R]]) :- trans([P]), write(' and '), trans([[Q],[R]]).
```

Terminal Output:

```
?- trans([[p],[q],[r]]).
p and q or r
true ;
q and r
true .
```

Comment: What are all the extra embedded brackets for? With the operators defined, you should able to just do, for example, `trans(P ^ Q) :- trans(P), write(' and '),trans(Q).` and `trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).` What's the meaning of `[P]` versus `P`?

Comment: For this example you can forget the operators. This code is to be used for CNF form. So input will be for example: `[[p,q],[q,r]]` which should output as `(p or q) and (q or r)`

The example I used that was incorrect is:
`trans([[p],[q],[r]])` should be `p and q and r` not `p and q or r`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this. There's a bit of splitting out of clauses to make the parenthesis come out nice.

```
% Handle the top, conjunction level

trans([H]) :-                  % A single atomic conjunctive term
    atom(H), write(H).
trans([H]) :-                  % A single non-atomic conjunctive term
    trans_dis(H).
trans([H1,H2|T]) :-            % Multiple conjunctive terms
    trans_conj([H1,H2|T]).

trans_conj([H1,H2|T]) :-       % Multiple conjunctive terms
    trans_conj([H1]), write(' and '), trans_conj([H2|T]).
trans_conj([H]) :-             % Single atomic conjunctive term
    atom(H), write(H).
trans_conj([[H]]) :-           % Last conjunctive term, single disjunction
    trans_dis([H]).
trans_conj([[H1,H2|T]]) :-     % Last conjunctive term, multiple disjunctions
    write('('), trans_dis([H1,H2|T]), write(')').

% Handle the disjunctions level

trans_dis([H]) :-              % Single disjunctive term
    atom(H), write(H).
trans_dis([~H]) :-             % Single negated disjunctive term
    atom(H), write('not '), write(H).
trans_dis([H1,H2|T]) :-        % Multiple disjunctive terms
    trans_dis([H1]), write(' or '), trans_dis([H2|T]).
```

Some test results:

```
| ?- trans([p]).
p

true ? a

no
| ?- trans([[p]]).
p

true ? a

no
| ?-  trans([p,q]).
p and q

true ? a

no
| ?-  trans([[p,q]]).
p or q

true ? a

no
| ?-  trans([[p],[q]]).
p and q

true ? a

no
| ?- trans([[p,r],[q]]).
(p or r) and q

true ? a

no
| ?- trans([[p,r],[q,s]]).
(p or r) and (q or s)

| ?- trans([[a,~b,c],[d,e],[f]]).
(a or not b or c) and (d or e) and f

true ? a

(1 ms) no
```

Answer (score 0):

You query:

```
?- trans([[p],[q],[r]]).
```

gets instantiated with

```
trans([P,Q,R]) :- trans([P]), write(' or '), trans([Q,R]).
```

(or: the 4th clause of `trans/1`). You want it to instantiate with

```
trans([[P],[Q],[R]]) :- trans([P]), write(' and '), trans([[Q],[R]]).
```

(or: the 10th clause of `trans/1`).

The reason why this happens is that `trans([[p],[q],[r]])` unifies with `[P,Q,R]` according to the following substitution: `P = [p]`, `Q = [q]`, and `R = [r]`.

#### Proper use of recursion

Your code looks a little verbose for Prolog code. I therefore give a possible rewrite here that uses recursion proper.

Instead of:

```
trans([P,Q]) :- trans(P), write(' or '), trans(Q).
trans([P,Q,R]) :- trans([P]), write(' or '), trans([Q,R]).
trans([P,Q,R,S]) :- trans([P]), write(' or '), trans([Q,R,S]).
```

you can also write:

```
trans([]).
trans([H|T]):-
  trans(H),
  trans(T).
```

... and that works for any list argument that is given to `trans/1`.

#### Distinguish disjunction from conjunction

You are not making the distinction between conjunction and disjunction correctly yet, you may want to try out:

```
trans(and([]).
trans(and([H])):-
  trans(H).
trans(and([H|T])):-
  trans(H),
  write(' and '),
  trans(and(T)).

trans(or([])).
trans(or([H])):-
  trans(H).
trans(or([H|T])):-
  trans(P),
  write(' or '),
  trans(or(T)).
```

Comment: I sort of understand where you are coming from however I think the implementation is off slightly as that currently does not work.

For the initial single variable, would it be `trans([H|T]):- trans(P), trans([T|X]).`

As surely for two or more variables trans([p,q,r,s]). It needs to keep calling trans([H|T])?

Comment: @ChrisShanks Indeed, a typo of mime (so much for writing code without running it...), `P` is now corrected to `H` in two places.

Comment: Should there be full stops after the third line of each code piece? before the next statement starts?

Comment: @ChrisShanks Indeed, added that too.